# How to copy a package to Node_Modules through manually in angular-2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

After copying the package to node_modules i am getting 404 error. Even i specified in package.json in dependencies...

Plz help me to fix this thing. Thank you.

In developer tool

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/ng2-pdf-viewer
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

So, node modules are libraries that add functionality to your application.  Angular has no way to know that you intend to make that functionality available at a given URL unless you code it to do so.

On the [ng2-pdf-viewer GitHub page](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer), scroll down to the Usage section to see an example of how they are implementing that in a custom component.

Essentially, you need to create a component in Angular, add that component to the router for the URL you want, and then code in the ng2-pdf-viewer functionality like in the example.  You can read more about how Angular routing works here: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I followed the same URL, and I have some limitations on my system to install, that's why I copied manually to node_modules.

Comment: URLs in Angular must be explicitly defined in the router, and the router can only route to components*.  When you visit `http://localhost:3000/ng2-pdf-viewer`, you are asking Angular to serve up the component matching `ng2-pdf-viewer` as defined in the router.  This is why yo are getting a 404.  The `node_modules` folder is entirely separate from the Angular router.

Comment: Yah, I agree with you router is to navigate between the components.But I checked for different package in developer tool and its showing correct path for that .http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs/operator/min.js and my package also it should suppose to show http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-pdf-viewer but its showing  http://localhost:3000/ng2-pdf-viewer

Comment: Ok, question then -- can you post your current route configuration for `http://localhost:3000/ng2-pdf-viewer` and corresponding component?  Maybe I can help you debug the 404 routing issue

Comment: import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
**import {PdfViewerModule} from 'ng2-pdf-viewer';**
import {CoordinatesComponent } from './coordinates.Component';
​const routes: Routes = [
     { path: '', component: CoordinatesComponent }
];
@NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule,FormsModule,RouterModule.forChild(routes),PdfViewerModule],
    declarations: [CoordinatesComponent],  
    exports: [ RouterModule] 
})
export class coordinatesModule { }

Comment: Ok, so you have imported ng2-pdf-viewer in your, but that doesn't mean there is a route for it.  Note the part: ` Routes = [ { path: '', component: CoordinatesComponent } ]`.  Those are your route declarations.  You will have to create a component, implement ng2-pdf-viewer like in its Readme, import that component into the router, and then declare a route for it.

Comment: (https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) in that url also he did not create any component he installed that package and imported into his module

Comment: Yes, he installed package, imported module, AND implemented in his component (https://imgur.com/a/Zlhy7).  The readme there assumes that you have a component that already exists and it properly routed.  This is a common pattern with Angular plugins, by importing the module you are making the ng2-pdf-viewer component available with the `<pdf-viewer>` tag.  I encourage you to go through the Tour of Heroes tutorial on the Angular 2+ website angular.io, it's very helpful.

Comment: Yah,I have component and  my routing is also working fine. I will go through again. Thanks for your time.